# What does it mean for a class of problems to have a "complete theory"?

Tags: optimization, terminology, definition, convex-optimization

In the preface of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook),  it is written that convex optimization problems have a "fairly complete theory".

My guess is that it means that the theory of convex optimization problems can identify when one can be solved or not solved and when one can be solved, there is always some theory that can used to arrive at a solution.

Comment: They don't mean the formal usage of "theory", just that most problems are solved.

Comment: @Don You cannot say that "most" problems are solved in an area of maths because no matter how much research has been done in this area, there's always an infinite amount of independent, "interesting-to-some-people" problems you could ask. So for me, when someone says that a theory is "fairly complete", what they really mean is that *they* are no longer interested in it, and that their time is better spent learning something else they *personally* find interesting/useful.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Agreed, although I think that's a somewhat pedantic point, since we define problems within a field to be those which are considered interesting to begin with.

Comment: Most likely it should say "a fairly extensive theory."